# styling input type checkbox

Tags: html, css

how can i style `<input type="checkbox">` tags?

i need to change border type and color...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something happens in *any* browser I'd be surprised. This is one of those outstanding form elements that browsers tend not to let you style that much, and that people usually try to replace with javascript so they can style/code something to look and act like a checkbox.

Here's an example: [prettyCheckboxes](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/).

Note that you could do this:

```
input[type=checkbox] { ... }
```

But that won't work in IE6 (and possibly IE7).